# An adjective to describe a man who acts and treats like a real man or like a woman

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

What adjective shall I use in the following sentences:

> 1) Girls like him because of his................ behavior/treatment. [the quality of acting like a real man, speaking in a manlike tone, treating like a man etc.]

a) masculine 
b) man-like [self-made term based on what we say in our language]

here I guess "a" sounds better.

> 2) Girls dislike him because of his................ behavior/treatment.

a) feminine 
b) womanish

here I think "a" works better.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the social terms.

= Girls like his manly behavior.

= Girls dislike his macho behavior.

Forget man-like. The adjective in English is manly.

- She had her own distinct style and tended to wear **mannish suits**.
  (suits that a man would wear, associated with men).
- She was a very **feminine dresser** but had a **mannish haircut**.
  (feminine=inclined to be what is associated with the female sex, rather than the male sex]
- He had very **effeminate brush strokes** when painting those canvases. [his manner was like a woman, "delicate", associated with women]
- She was just a young girl but really **sounded womanish**. [like a woman, associated with a woman]
- Checking for dust with your forefinger really **seems womanish** to me.
- Your husband seems to have a **womanish obsession** with cleanliness.

Depending on context, womanish and effeminate can be read in a pejorative sense but they are not always used that way. ish generally means like the noun that precedes it.

Comment: Thank you @Lambie. I wonder if you could add to your answer regarding (**mannish/womanish/feminine and effeminate**) too.

Comment: Thank you very much @Lambie but I think "macho" just means ("too" manly) while I was going to say something opposite to that! I guess both "womanish" and "effeminate" work when you are talking about feminine wualities of a man to show your disapproval. Do you agree?

Comment: @A-friend manly behavior and macho behavior would not be the same thing. womanish is woman + ish (like a woman) and effeminate means two things: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effeminate

Answer (score 3):

Both Masculine and Feminine are original terms having the meaning manlike and womanish respectively, so why make up a word when there already a word exists that describes the meaning you want to deliver?
So yes, (a) is better to use in both cases.

Comment: For sentence 2) I would suggest the related word [_effeminate_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effeminate) as an alternative to _feminine_.

Comment: Well @Bella Swan, because most of the error-recognition apps and web sites find it as an error. I don't know why. However I just heard once it was used in this sense by a none-native.